# Can we specify when badges will appear?

Tags: feature-request, badges

I've been trying to get the 'Fanatic' badge for around a year now, and yesterday I finally got it. Or so I thought. The badge didn't appear.

A quick search revealed that it took some time to appear. It seems to me that we could prevent some undue worry and questions by simply stating on the 'Congratulations' message (when viewing your profile where the badges are tracked), that the badge should appear within X days (I do not know how long it takes, not having actually received it yet).

Is this a reasonable request?

EDIT: The badge appeared for me within 24 hours of obtaining it.

Comment: Good question.  I'm sometimes surprised by the "congratulations" message followed by no badge, too.  I think the badge code is pretty erratic, unfortunately.  (I've now been waiting more than a day to even get the "congratulations" message for a tag badge I earned on another site.  Weird.)

Comment: Further information I've just learned: after Friday's server fail-over, automatic scripts including badge awards weren't running for a while.  So that delayed both our awards.  Normally you should get the badge within several hours of the "congratulations" message.